# ¿Como mostrar este json que recibo en mi backend en mi fronted?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

¿Como mostrar este json que recibo en mi backend en mi fronted?

```
const express = require('express');
const wkd = require('steem');

var query = ['myusername'];

wkd.api.getAccounts(query, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

lo que se recibe una vez ejecutado el programa.

JSON:

```
[ { id: 1689,
    name: 'amar',
    owner: { weight_threshold: 1, account_auths: [], key_auths: [Array] },
    active: { weight_threshold: 1, account_auths: [], key_auths: [Array] },
    posting: { weight_threshold: 1, account_auths: [], key_auths: [Array] },
    memo_key: 'WKA7k6W6qXHj7bN2z1MLDiVexTwheUgjoFxH7HQbQZhz61uGiD8RD',
    json_metadata: '{"profile":{"profile_image":"http://i67.tinypic.com/b67zgw.jpg","cover_image":"http://i66.tinypic.com/2vlv09y.gif","name":"Amar","about":"Join our discord : https://discord.gg/ffrE9BZ","location":"Nepal  ","website":"https://whaleshares.io/@amar"}}',
    proxy: '',
    last_owner_update: '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
    last_account_update: '2019-01-02T10:56:42',
    created: '2018-09-05T09:58:06',
    mined: false,
    owner_challenged: false,
    active_challenged: false,
    last_owner_proved: '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
    last_active_proved: '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
    recovery_account: 'initminer',
    last_account_recovery: '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
    reset_account: 'null',
    comment_count: 0,
    lifetime_vote_count: 0,
    post_count: 2554,
    can_vote: true,
    voting_power: 9011,
    last_vote_time: '2019-01-22T17:21:21',
    balance: '189.000 WEKU',
    savings_balance: '150.000 WEKU',
    sbd_balance: '584.897 WKD',
    sbd_seconds: '447913370259',
    sbd_seconds_last_update: '2019-01-22T17:18:51',
    sbd_last_interest_payment: '2019-01-13T06:07:51',
    savings_sbd_balance: '103.009 WKD',
    savings_sbd_seconds: '0',
    savings_sbd_seconds_last_update: '2018-10-24T04:15:45',
    savings_sbd_last_interest_payment: '2018-10-24T04:15:45',
    savings_withdraw_requests: 0,
    reward_sbd_balance: '0.000 WKD',
    reward_steem_balance: '0.000 WEKU',
    reward_vesting_balance: '0.000000 VESTS',
    reward_vesting_steem: '0.000 WEKU',
    vesting_shares: '8798609765.450194 VESTS',
    delegated_vesting_shares: '0.000000 VESTS',
    received_vesting_shares: '9990297942.000000 VESTS',
    vesting_withdraw_rate: '0.000000 VESTS',
    next_vesting_withdrawal: '1969-12-31T23:59:59',
    withdrawn: 0,
    to_withdraw: 0,
    withdraw_routes: 0,
    curation_rewards: 37658275,
    posting_rewards: 119042513,
    proxied_vsf_votes: [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    witnesses_voted_for: 0,
    average_bandwidth: '248433726146',
    lifetime_bandwidth: '7054822000000',
    last_bandwidth_update: '2019-01-22T17:21:21',
    average_market_bandwidth: '66287432709',
    lifetime_market_bandwidth: '1137240000000',
    last_market_bandwidth_update: '2019-01-13T17:20:45',
    last_post: '2019-01-22T16:33:09',
    last_root_post: '2019-01-22T04:56:30',
    vesting_balance: '0.000 WEKU',
    reputation: '1788310326941346',
    transfer_history: [],
    market_history: [],
    post_history: [],
    vote_history: [],
    other_history: [],
    witness_votes: [],
    tags_usage: [],
    guest_bloggers: [] } ]
```

steemjs solo se ejecuta de lado de el server, entonces la res que recibo de la función quisiera saber como mostrarla en mi frontend?

Comment: Pues como tu quieras. Lo que estas reciviendo lo puedes transformar en alguna plantilla de html y mostrarlo como te guste.

Comment: pero como? es que no entiendo ese punto se usar ejs pero no se como enviar lo que recibo de esa funcion a html. :/

Comment: Que tecnologia estas usando para el front? Ese codigo que muestras parece de expressjs que sirve tambien para renderizar paginas, pero te recomiendo que no lo hagas directamente. Trabajar de esa manera te permite mantener serparado tu codigo para desarrollar multiples interfaces como lo son app de android, ios, web, etc. Una opcion es angular. Tambien react que estan orientados al front.

Comment: no, steem solo funciona de lado de el servidor. por eso decir de como interpretar la res que recibo de esa funcion en html.

Comment: Seria bueno que actualizaras tu pregunta con la idea que tienes en mente para mostrar esa informacion. Asi como me lo planteas no tiene sentido querer interpretar html en el lado del servidor si ya estas resiviendo la info ordenada para ese fin. El html te servira para presentarla. Como la quieres presentar y de que manera lo quieres hacer?

Comment: vale, pues eso como presento ese json en html no tengo idea de como?

Comment: ya actualice :p

Comment: Bueno, asi cambia un poquitin la cosa. Pero ahi tee va un tuto en ingles para que te des una idea de como trabajar el front. https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer un print de tu Json en el front, solo tienes que enviarlo, si estas utilizando express, es bastante facil, puedes renderizarlo con algún motor para tus views o simplemente enviarlo, incluso sin express puedes hacerlo así, mira este ejemplo.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const wkd = require('steem');

var query = ['myusername'];
let myjson;

wkd.api.getAccounts(query, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
  myjson = res;
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(myjson, null, 2)+"</pre>") // Esto le dará un formato indentado.
});
```

Luego cuando un usuario entre a tu ruta se vera un código pre formateado como este (***ejecutar***):

```js
var myjson =  {array: [1,2,3], anotherObject: "Hey I´m an object!"}
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(myjson, null, 2)+"</pre>"
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, ¡Un saludo!.

Comment: excelente justo lo que buscaba hacer, muchísimas gracias. ahora a usar ejs.

Comment: perdón por revivir pero tengo dudas sobre este mismo tema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233736/ayuda-con-json-sus-propiedades-no-se-muestran