# Ayuda con JSON, sus propiedades no se muestran

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs

Cuando envío el json a la vista de de mi ejs y intento seleccionar alguna de sus propiedades no me muestra nada.

Mi código:

Express Router

```
const express = require('express');
const wkd = require('steem');
const router = express.Router();

var query = ['hadrien.rivere'];

let myjson;

wkd.api.getAccounts(query, function(err, res) {
    myjson = res;
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/index.ejs', {
        enviar: myjson
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

El json a usar una vez que se ejecute la función: wkd.api.getAccounts

```
[
  {
    "id": 51421,
    "name": "hadrien.rivere",
    "owner": {
      "weight_threshold": 1,
      "account_auths": [],
      "key_auths": [
        [
          "WKA5MiBd8XWvnhAtvCJBcvnuPrPco8ybnzQA6RyPhYrZjdy6g3AY1",
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    "active": {
      "weight_threshold": 1,
      "account_auths": [],
      "key_auths": [
        [
          "WKA5xYEEH9K3ZcUvMgzf4t1QLBkVZDubeoUfrH3Gz7xfJmRdDQpTt",
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    "posting": {
      "weight_threshold": 1,
      "account_auths": [],
      "key_auths": [
        [
          "WKA5dghrkyYfqQv4RFyPFPNhetktc5j9n58J6qAxNQYyuXacwUaoW",
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    "memo_key": "WKA5NEg1Y727yXtJFXAXQEHprRkZDRJQfq3b2Cvsi8vtc4g1MbxW5",
    "json_metadata": "{\"profile\":{\"name\":\"Hadrien Rivere\",\"about\":\"Php & Javascript Developer.\",\"location\":\"Ciudad de Mexico\",\"website\":\"https://wekunow.com\",\"profile_image\":\"https://scontent.fmex10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/30709565_1503264209778166_3085169884544368640_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.fmex10-1.fna&oh=6cecbf65434425f822e77680897a5f43&oe=5C6DB52C\",\"cover_image\":\"https://scontent.fmex10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/45358979_1756777437760174_1051862869752152064_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ht=scontent.fmex10-1.fna&oh=3aa95388801763faf786790cd21a91a9&oe=5C9B5290\"}}",
    "proxy": "",
    "last_owner_update": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "last_account_update": "2018-12-25T06:14:51",
    "created": "2018-12-03T18:32:24",
    "mined": false,
    "owner_challenged": false,
    "active_challenged": false,
    "last_owner_proved": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "last_active_proved": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "recovery_account": "initminer",
    "last_account_recovery": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "reset_account": "null",
    "comment_count": 0,
    "lifetime_vote_count": 0,
    "post_count": 104,
    "can_vote": true,
    "voting_power": 9411,
    "last_vote_time": "2019-01-29T17:53:54",
    "balance": "0.000 WEKU",
    "savings_balance": "0.000 WEKU",
    "sbd_balance": "684.704 WKD",
    "sbd_seconds": "469841350419",
    "sbd_seconds_last_update": "2019-01-29T02:39:24",
    "sbd_last_interest_payment": "2019-01-12T22:50:15",
    "savings_sbd_balance": "0.000 WKD",
    "savings_sbd_seconds": "0",
    "savings_sbd_seconds_last_update": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "savings_sbd_last_interest_payment": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
    "savings_withdraw_requests": 0,
    "reward_sbd_balance": "0.000 WKD",
    "reward_steem_balance": "0.000 WEKU",
    "reward_vesting_balance": "446018.975538 VESTS",
    "reward_vesting_steem": "8.115 WEKU",
    "vesting_shares": "314730428.386420 VESTS",
    "delegated_vesting_shares": "0.000000 VESTS",
    "received_vesting_shares": "11000000.000000 VESTS",
    "vesting_withdraw_rate": "0.000000 VESTS",
    "next_vesting_withdrawal": "1969-12-31T23:59:59",
    "withdrawn": 0,
    "to_withdraw": 0,
    "withdraw_routes": 0,
    "curation_rewards": 76001,
    "posting_rewards": 1264554,
    "proxied_vsf_votes": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "witnesses_voted_for": 0,
    "average_bandwidth": "12091321532",
    "lifetime_bandwidth": "89954000000",
    "last_bandwidth_update": "2019-01-29T17:53:54",
    "average_market_bandwidth": 1250000000,
    "lifetime_market_bandwidth": 1250000000,
    "last_market_bandwidth_update": "2018-12-06T16:18:18",
    "last_post": "2019-01-28T01:32:24",
    "last_root_post": "2019-01-20T03:39:36",
    "vesting_balance": "0.000 WEKU",
    "reputation": "34368576011895",
    "transfer_history": [],
    "market_history": [],
    "post_history": [],
    "vote_history": [],
    "other_history": [],
    "witness_votes": [],
    "tags_usage": [],
    "guest_bloggers": []
  }
]
```

Mi ejs index.ejs

```
<% test = JSON.stringify(enviar) %>

<% for (var i in test) { %>
    <%= test[i].name%>
<% } %>
```

Ayuda  :/

Comment: Hola, me parece que el problema está en que asumes que el resultado devuelto por `wkd.api.getAccounts()` es un JSON, cuando en realidad es un `array` que contiene un JSON. ¿Porque no pruebas haciendo lo siguiente: `myjson = res[0];` y comentas los resultados?

Comment: efectivamente asi es lo solucione haciendo esto en ejs.                                <% for (var i in enviar) { %>
 <% var author = JSON.stringify(enviar[i].author)%>
 <% var aut = JSON.parse(author)%>
 <%=aut%>
<% } %>                                                                                                     El problema es que tengo ahora un json_metadata en el mismo array y no puedo iterar esa sección. :/      {"tags":["community-deals","zealpro","howto","it","technology"],"image":["https://res"]}

Comment: bueno en el array json que pongo arriba esta "json_metadata": esto no lo puedo iterar :/

Comment: ¿Cómo estás tratando de iterarlo? primero debes convertirlo en un objeto JS. Para eso puedes hacer lo siguiente. Supongamos que `myjson = res[0]` contiene el resultado que esperas y supongamos que tu clave `json_metadata` contiene el string metadata que deseas iterar. Puedes hacer lo siguiente para convertir ese string en un JSON: `myjson.json_metadata = JSON.parse(myjson.json_metadata);`. Ahora tu clave `json_metadata` contiene un objeto JS que podrás iterar. Comenta los resultados.